# Fragment backstack issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm currently trying to create app navigation via navigation drawer. So I can open fragments **A1/B1/C1** from drawer for example. They are replacing each other in my container view so backstack should be empty. 
I use this code on drawer selection:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentToShow, null)
                .commit();
```

From **A1** I can go to **A2**. **A2**-fragment should be added in the same container. For this case:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

There should be 1 fragment in backstack.

It all kinda works but there is an issue. If I open navigation drawer more than one time and trying to open **A1** again, **A1** to **A2** back and forth then on Back button press from **A1** I get crash with exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added`

In `onBackPressed` of my Activity I have:

```
    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
```

backStackEntryCount is more than 0 when it shouldn't be.

Can you give me some points to think. Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put a tag to your fragments when you call replace. If this is not enough, you can try to remove the fragment (by its tag) before calling replace

Also, why don't you call addToBackStack on the first call?

Comment: I didn't call addToBackStack on first call because I don't want to put fragments which open from navigation drawer to be in backstack. I want them to replace each other.

Comment: @P_King Were you able to solve this. I'm having similar issue. I have a bottom nav bar for which I add only one fragment to backstack and suppose a different fragment (not part of nav bar) is drawn on top of this and I do orientation change, a back press causes crash due to same reason as yours.